# Pinging in Python

Tags: python-3.x, ping

i started to learn python so i tried to make a program that takes `host.txt` and for each line of `host.txt` try to ping,at the end shows all the good answers.But the problem is it just works fine for last line of `host.txt` and it says others not reachable(like google.com)but if you put them in last line it works fine.What should i do?
My code:

```
import platform    # For getting the operating system name
import subprocess  # For executing a shell command

ip_addresses = []
i = 1
j = 1.0
z = 1.0
alive_addresses = []

f = open("host.txt", "r")
for x in f:                                                                     
    ip_addresses.append(x)
    i += 1
         
    
#readfile()


def ping(host,i,j,z):
    """
    Returns True if host (str) responds to a ping request.
    Remember that a host may not respond to a ping (ICMP) request even if the host name is valid.
    """

    # Option for the number of packets as a function of
    param = '-n' if platform.system().lower()=='windows' else '-c'

    # Building the command. Ex: "ping -c 1 google.com"
    command = ['ping', param, '10', host]
    result = subprocess.call(command)
    if result == 0:
        print("%s is Alive ===> %s" %(host,z) + '%')
        alive_addresses.append(host)

    
    else:
        print("%s is Dead ===> %s" %(host,z) + '%')
    
    
for x in ip_addresses:
    try:
        ping(x,i,j,z)
        j += 1
        z = round((j/i), 1) * 100
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        z = 0

print("")
print("")
for x in alive_addresses:
    print("%s is Alive" %(x))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace `command = ['ping', param, '10', host]` with `command = ['ping', param, '10', host.strip()]`, From my testing there are invalid characters (newlines) at the end of your addresses and subprocess doesnt ignore those like a shell/CMD would

Inserting

```
print("DBG: '"+host+"' / '"+host.strip()+"'})")
```

Prints

```
DBG: '1.1.1.1
' / '1.1.1.1'})
```

Showing you the newline character.

You should generally always `strip`/`trim` strings when working with lines where whitespaces at the start and end are not important.